# How to add new elements to an array of a user-defined type?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have converted some stored procedure from Oracle to PostgreSQL but faced the below issue:

I have a user-defined type in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TYPE ut_merci_row AS (    
   SGLCNTNR varchar(100),
   CODEST_MERCEVARIA varchar(50), 
   CODCICLO smallint 
);

CREATE TYPE ut_merci_table AS (ut_merci_table UT_MERCI_ROW[]);
```

In Oracle:

```
  retTable UT_MERCI_TABLE := UT_MERCI_TABLE();
  .....
  retTable.extend;
  retTable(retTable.last) := UT_MERCI_ROW(rec.SGLCNTNR,rec.CODEST_MERCEVARIA,rec.CODCICLO);
```

Could you advise me how to convert the 2 last below code lines to PostgreSQL?

```
  retTable.extend;
  retTable(retTable.last) := UT_MERCI_ROW(rec.SGLCNTNR,rec.CODEST_MERCEVARIA,rec.CODCICLO);
```

Someone said that we don't need to "extend" the collection in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply append the value to the array using the `||` concatenation operator. Make sure you initialize the variable to an empty array (otherwise it would `null`)

```
retTable ut_merci_row[] := '{}';
```

Then in the loop, just append a value of the type to the array:

```
retTable := rettable || row(rec.SGLCNTNR,rec.CODEST_MERCEVARIA,rec.CODCICLO)::ut_merci_row;
```

---

Trying to mimic Oracle's complicated way of returning tables with a cursor and custom types is not the right way to do this in Postgres.

But a much better solution would be to get rid of all that cursor processing and array handling and return a set of the base type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uf_getstatomerce1() 
  returns setof ut_merci_row
AS $body$
   SELECT DISTINCT row(m.SGLCNTNR, m.CODEST_MERCEVARIA, 1 as CODCICLO)::ut_merci_row
   from merce.DELIVERY_ORDER_RIF rif
     inner join merce.DELIVERY_ORDER_PARTITA pm on rif.DO_ID = pm.DO_ID
     inner join merce.vPARTITEMERCE m on pm.CODPARTITAMERCE = m.CODPARTITAMERCE;
$body$
LANGUAGE sql
STABLE;
```

In fact, in Postgres you also don't need a custom type for this, just declare the function as `returns table` and forget all the overhead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uf_getstatomerce1() 
  returns table (SGLCNTNR varchar, CODEST_MERCEVARIA varchar, CODCICLO smallint )
AS $body$
   SELECT DISTINCT row(m.SGLCNTNR, m.CODEST_MERCEVARIA, 1 as CODCICLO)::ut_merci_row
   from merce.DELIVERY_ORDER_RIF rif
     inner join merce.DELIVERY_ORDER_PARTITA pm on rif.DO_ID = pm.DO_ID
     inner join merce.vPARTITEMERCE m on pm.CODPARTITAMERCE = m.CODPARTITAMERCE;
$body$
LANGUAGE sql
STABLE;
```

The SQL function that simply returns a query will be **much** more efficient than the cursor loop.

In both cases, you can use it like this:

```
select *
from uf_getstatomerce1() ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated the function to return RETURNS ut_merci_row[] instead of RETURNS UT_MERCI_TABLE. And the return result is an array of ut_merci_row objects? Can't we use RETURNS UT_MERCI_TABLE?

Comment: @ThaiLe: you don't need that kludge with the `ut_merci_table` just return an array of that record. Or even better, don't define the function as `returns table` and get rid of the slow cursor processing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explains. I will update the function with these.

Answer (score 0):

The second type definition is pretty redundant, just use `ut_merci_row[]`.

You don't have to “extend” an array in PostgreSQL, just assign to an index that is not yet used.